# Import R function exported from package A into B by C package

Tags: r, import

This seems to be a weird question but for me makes total sense. I need to import a function from package A, which was imported/exported into package B using `@importFrom` into a function in package C (which doesn't import package A by default). I'd like to do this because I don't want to add another dependency on package C (package A). If package A is already a dependency from package B, and package B a dependency on package C, shouldn't I be able to import A's functions exported into package B to be used into C package?

I guess this is what I'd like to do: `fun <- B::A::function_from_a()`

Is it possible? Is there a different syntax I could try to achieve this?

##### UPDATE: Further information given the comments

If in package B `@importFrom A function_from_a` was used, simply using `@importFrom B function_from_a` will work. But, if in package B `@import A` was used, it seems it's not straightforward because you'd get the warning `object ‘function_from_a’ is not exported by 'namespace:B'`.

Comment: If package B exports the function imported from package A, you can just importfrom package B?

Comment: If you have a dependency on package A, and package A has a dependency on package B, then you have a dependency on package B already, so you may as well import directly from B. I'm not really the goal of a more complicated syntax involving B.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. But if I include `@importFrom packB function_from_a`, I get `object ‘function_from_a’ is not exported by 'namespace:packB'`. I think this happens when `@import packB` is used instead of explicitly using `@importFrom`

Comment: It doesn't sound like in your example that B reexports the function it imported from A. If that function is not exported from B, you cannot import it. You need to directly depends on A. You cannot import things that are not exported. This is difficult to discuss in the abstract. It would be easier to provide some sort of reproducible example that has something we can actually test with with to verify what's going on.

Comment: I completely agree with @MrFlick - it basically seems like package B isn't relevant at all here. Why not just directly refer to the function you want from A directly?

Answer (score 1):

You want to do this because you want to avoid adding another dependency. However you already have this dependency. If package B imports package A and you're already requiring package B then your package will require package A to be installed no matter what you do. It's essentially a silent dependency - just because you aren't listing it in the imports or depends doesn't mean it doesn't need to be installed.

So just bite the bullet and directly import the function from A.